# Trying to send an email with PHP from HTML form resulting in an HTTP Error 405

Tags: php, html, http

So I wanted to make a contact form for a website that can actually send emails, but ended up with this error : [image: error]

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="contact-fast">
      <div class="contact-form">
        <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="contact-form-handler.php">
          <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required> <br>
          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required> <br>
          <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="8" required></textarea> <br>
          <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my PHP code:

```
    <?php 

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $email_from = 'skeremobiel@gmail.com';

  $email_subject = 'New Mail From Website';

  $email_body = "Username: $name.\n".
                "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                "User Message: $message.\n";

  
  $to = "said444b@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";


  if ($visitor_email!=NULL) {
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
  }
  

  header("Location: http://127.0.0.1:5500/social.html");
  die()
  

?>
```

Here's how my page looks like before and after submitting the form:

[image: page before submitting]

[image: page after submitting]

I think the problem is that when i click on the submit button i get directed to 127.0.0.1:5500/contact-form-handler.php (as you can see in the last image in my question). It doesn't execute the php file, but it just opens it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check your server error log to see why it's getting 405 error.

Comment: @Barmar how can i do this on linux?

Comment: It depends on which webserver you're using as well. You should be able to locate the error log for your o/s and webserver combination by reading documentation and/or simple googling

Answer (score -2):

Many things can go wrong.

Make shure php error reporting is on. Google for that.

Try to find where the error code is coming from by reducing your problem.
For instance, comment out mail() and see if it works.

Or replace your php code by a simple text to see if the code runs, if the text appears on your browser screen.

Or Google for error 405. You will learn it is an http error, something in the data exchange between your browser and the server.

Do you have characters before `<?php` because if you have, the server will not be able to output the HTTP header any more.

Is your php file located at the webserver root and called contact-form-handler.php?

Comment: I just tried that out. Didn't change anything. I think the problem is that when i click on the submit button i get directed to http://127.0.0.1:5500/contact-form-handler.php (as you can see in the last image in my question). It doesn't execute the php file, but it just opens it.

Comment: did you check `error_log` file - root in apache